# Unable to send mail with attachment with JavaMailSender and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm unable to send a mail with an attachment from a Spring Boot application. Spring boot version 2.2.13.RELEASE. No exception thrown. Sending a mail without an attachment works fine.

```
val file = File.createTempFile("filename", ".csv")
file.setExecutable(true)
file.setReadable(true)
file.setWritable(true)


try {
            val message = emailSender.createMimeMessage()
            val helper = MimeMessageHelper(message, true)

            helper.addAttachment("File", file)
            helper.setFrom("noreply@mydomain.org")
            helper.setTo("mail@mydomain.org")
            helper.setSubject("dummy subject")
            helper.setText("Dummy text", true)

            emailSender.send(message)
        } catch (exception: MailException) {
            println(exception.toString())
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it with class FileSystemResource?

It will be then something like this:

```
helper.addAttachment("file.csv", new FileSystemResource(file));
```

Also in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#addAttachment-java.lang.String-javax.activation.DataSource-) it states that:

`attachmentFilename` - the name of the attachment as it will appear in the mail (the content type will be determined by this)

So always add extension to fileName in method MimeMessageHelper.addAtachment() .

Comment: Still didn´t work :( I used file.name for the name which outputs the filename with extension

Comment: Did you try converting to byte[] and then use ByteArrayResource or ByteDataArrayResource? Also, I just noticed that you first attached file then you're setting "from", "to", "subject" and "text". I know it is important to call this methods in right order. First you must set "text" then you can add attachment.